# Alternative (back of box) builds of 7822 Railway Station - is there an 'official' configuration where the track terminates at the station?

Tags: trains, instructions, vintage

I am looking for a scan or photo of the back of the box of the [7822 Railway Station](https://brickset.com/sets/7822-1/Railway-Station) [image]

**Background:**

As is common with Lego sets, there are a number of alternative builds pictured on the back of the set box and sometimes in the instructions themselves.

Some time ago I found a website with a picture of an alternative build of the 7822 set that was described as an 'alternative build'. Sadly I can't find the picture again but the configuration of the station was such that the train line servicing the station terminated at the platform, and did not continue on though as it does in the main build. It is this configuration in particular that I am interested in.

**Known alternative builds:**

There are various depictions of other alternative builds available on the internet, one such that shows two different configurations in the same picture is [this scene from the back page of the 7834 Level Crossing](http://www.peeron.com/scans/7834-1/11) <sup>(Note: The version in the middle of the page on the right may be the one I am interested in, but I can't see the position of the track in that picture.)</sup>

The YouTube video ['LEGO 12V Train Dream Layout'](http://youtu.be/OcSbxAU672w) shows the alternative build from the top of the 7834 instruction scan at around the 0:20 position in the video opposite another set in the main build configuration.

**Answering this question:**

I am very happy to receive answers on any of the possible alternative builds for the 7822 Railway Station and make this question a resource for anyone interested in different configurations, but the accepted answer will be for a clear scan or photo of the back of the 7822 box. (It may or may not show the configuration I am thinking of as the mysterious picture on the internet that I am thinking of may or may not have been an 'official Lego created' alternative build).

Comment: If no one comes up with anything here, you could write an email to LEGO directly and ask for the images. They might be able to help you: http://service.lego.com/en-us/contactus/

Comment: I contacted LEGO customer service and got this reply: "We wish we could provide pictures of your older LEGO® train set but unfortunately, they aren't available through us. There is hope though, Peeron.com is website run by a group of LEGO fans that contains information on LEGO sets, replacement parts, building instructions and more. It’s not affiliated with the LEGO Group but we know from other fans that it has a good collection of older building instructions to download, discontinued pieces to purchase, and great set information.". Of course I had already checked Peeron.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here you go: http://goichot.free.fr/lego/7822/8.JPG

Have been looking myself for hours as I have two 7822 sets but no box...

[image: 7822]

Comment: With the way I run my trains, there's no way I'd allow any minifig to sit on the yellow seats. Wait, yes I would :-/

Answer (score 3):

While it's not the "official" answer you're looking for, you could add the a bumper just outside the station, like this guy has:

http://www.freelug.org/spip.php?article558

Comment: Thanks for the interesting link but I'm not sure it really answers the question. However I think the buffer designs will be useful for other projects.

Comment: I thought the question, as you asked it, was how to get an end-of-the-line at the train station. My suggestion, then, was to simply add a buffer right outside, and call it a day. Was that not the question you wanted answered? (I know it wasn't the answer you were expecting but I figured it could be a useful stop-gap.)