# LEGO Trains 12v: Identify This?

Tags: trains, set-identification, city, 12v

This is a very popular picture, which almost all LEGO Trains' fans from the 1980s would recognize.

I have the train in the foreground, [7740](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?set=7740-1), but not the 4th car (the red one). Can anyone please clarify that from where it came? Also, what other trains are being shown here?

The two stations are probably the same model ([7822](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=7822-1)), just different builds. Level crossing (on left corner) is [7834](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?set=7834-1).

[image: LEGO Trains 12v - 1980s]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The red car that you mentioned is [Mail Van (7820)](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=7820-1).

[image: 7820]

There are a number of other trains in the picture including:

[7730](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=7730-1) - Goods train (the locomotive doesn't seem to be visible)

[image: 7730]

[7710](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=7710-1) - Push-Along Passenger Steam Train (just the cars)

[image: 7710]

[7750](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=7750-1) - Steam Engine with Tender (pulling the cars from 7710)

[image: 7750]

[7814](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=7814-1) - Crane Wagon

[image: 7814]

[7760](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=7760-1) - Diesel Shunter Locomotive

[image: 7760]

[7720](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=7720-1) - Diesel Freight Train Set (the car in the bottom right carrying rails to the work crew)

[image: 7720]

It's not a train, but set [6647 - Highway Repair](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=6647-1) is also present.

[image: 6647]

Comment: Oh man, what a great and detailed answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: BTW, do you know if the train station in the foreground is really another build of 7822?

Comment: I noticed that 7710, 7720, 7730 and 7750 are mixed in to three trains. They don't appear individually.

Comment: Regarding the alternative build of 7822 question: The station at the back is indeed an alternative of 7822 as can be seen on the back of the box, see [this answer](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/1743/789) to my question. As for the other build, I would guess it is another alternative build of the 7822, but I can't find any reference to it on the box or in the [instruction manual](http://www.peeron.com/scans/7822-1)